# jQuery Dynamic Adding

Tags: jquery

So I have the following code which works:

```
var a = $("#sample_1").dataTable().fnAddData( [
     domEle['AGENCY_NAME'],
     domEle['ADVERTISER_NAME'],
     domEle['CAMPAIGN_NAME'],
     domEle['STRATEGY_NAME'],
     domEle['IMPRESSIONS'],
     domEle['CLICKS'],
     domEle['PC_CONVERSIONS'],
     domEle['PV_CONVERSIONS'],
     domEle['ADJ_PV_CONVERSIONS'],
     domEle['eCPM'],
     domEle['eCPA'],
     domEle['eCPC'],
     domEle['MEDIA_COST'],
     domEle['TOTAL_SPEND'],
]);
```

However I want to display the columns in the order which is returned in AJAX so I want to change it to this:

```
var a = $("#sample_1").dataTable().fnAddData( [
     $.each(data['columns_order'], function(key, value){

          domEle[data['columns_order'][key]['fieldy']],

      });
]);
```

But I keep getting the following error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) "`.

Comment: did you try without the ',' ? i dont see why it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but i think the problem is that  , at the end, after domEle[data['columns_order'][key]['fieldy']]

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $("#sample_1").dataTable().fnAddData({
     $.each(data['columns_order'], function(key, value){

      domEle[data['columns_order'][key]['fieldy']],

  });
});
```

Copy paste the above code.You have missed some brackets in your code

Comment: This dosen't work. You changed the open square brackets to a curly bracket which is incorrect.